# How to force TToolBar Dessendent from TToolWindow using BidiMode Right To Left

Tags: api, delphi, vcl

I have a TMainMenu Related with a TToolBar(TToolWindow) how to force TToolBar using BidiMode RightToLeft Mode.
i try all Tricks to force it but my Solutions didn't successful....
i have this code here :

```
procedure Make_ToolBar_RTL(Control: TToolWindow);
var
OldLong: LongWord;
DWriteTextFormat: IDWriteTextFormat; // uses Winapi.D2D1.pas
begin
   OldLong := GetWindowLong(Control.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
   Control.BiDiMode := bdLeftToRight;
   SetWindowLong(Control.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, OldLong  or WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL); //WS_EX_RTLREADING & WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL
   Control.Repaint;
   //  DWriteTextFormat.SetReadingDirection(DWRITE_READING_DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT); from: Winapi.D2D1.pas
end;
```

i success to force it RTL but i face another problem with Text Rendering Upturned AND i go to MSDN site to search how to fix this issue above
i get this link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/how-to-ensure-text-is-displayed-with-the-correct-reading-direction) i think i need to use the commented code with using the *SetReadingDirection*

---

please any Advice i'm listening...

Answer (score 0):

use LMD Components it's has a very nice and customisable components (TElMainMenu & TElMenuBar)